# Tensorflow : How to get tensor name from Tensorboard?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I downloaded a [ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29.tar.gz) from tensorflow detection model zoo. And I used [import_pb_to_tensorboard.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/import_pb_to_tensorboard.py) to show the structure on Tensorboard.

I find a node named 'image_tensor',  [*this is the picture discribed in Tensorboard*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Diye.png). 
[image]

I want to use the function  'get_tensor_by_name()'  to input a new image and get the ouputs. However, it failed.

I tried 'get_operation_by_name()' , it didn't work neither.

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def one_image(im_path, model_path):
    sess= tf.Session()
    with sess.as_default():
        image_tensor = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file(im_path), channels=3)
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_path + "/model.ckpt.meta")
        saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path))
        graph = tf.get_default_graph()

        # x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("import/image_tensor:0")
        # out_put = graph.get_tensor_by_name("import/detection_classes:0")

        x = graph.get_operation_by_name("import/image_tensor").outputs[0]
        outputs = graph.get_operation_by_name("import/detection_classes").outputs[0]
        out_put = sess.run(outputs, feed_dict={x: image_tensor.eval()})

        print(out_put)
        sess.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    one_image("testimg-4-resize.jpg", "ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29")
```

And here is the KeyError:

```
KeyError: "The name 'import/image_tensor' refers to an Operation not in the graph."
```

I am wondering how to get the tensor name from Tensorboard and whether there is another way to load model from '*only-ckpts*'.

'*only-ckpts*' means files only include '***model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001***' , '***model.ckpt.index***' and '***model.ckpt.meta***'.

Any advice will be grateful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool `import_pb_to_tensorboard.py` [uses `tf.import_graph_def` to import the graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/import_pb_to_tensorboard.py#L45-L49) and uses default `name` argument, which is [`"import"` as documented](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/import_graph_def).

Your code imports the graph through `tf.train.import_meta_graph` and uses default `import_scope` argument, which will not prefix imported tensor or operation name. It is obvious then you have two options to correct this error:

1. Do the following in place of your `import_meta_graph` line:

   ```
   saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_path + "/model.ckpt.meta",
                                      import_scope='import')
   ```
2. Remove `import/` prefix when trying to get tensor or operation by name like this:

   ```
   x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("image_tensor:0")
   out_put = graph.get_tensor_by_name("detection_classes:0")

   x = graph.get_operation_by_name("image_tensor").outputs[0]
   outputs = graph.get_operation_by_name("detection_classes").outputs[0]
   ```